# How to initialize the controller $scope variables in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, initialization

I have one view where I am accessing scope variables from on angular controller function.

```
$scope.getCurrentTab = function (tab) {
 $scope.yourReportEnabled = (tab === 'REPORTS');
 $scope.currentTab = tab;
}
```

in the view I have two anchors on click of which I call `getCurrentTab()` by passing the tab name as a parameter.

Here the scope are variables defined in the function getCurrentTab which will be initialized only on the function call.

But if I define these variables outside the function these `gets initialized multiple times`.

So is there a way to define the scope `variables only once` which will be modified by `getCurrentTab` function only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either move them to a controller higher up the hierarchy (which doesn't get re-initialized during tab change) or move them to a service/factory, which will effectively be a singleton in your app.

Comment: are you using this function to keep track of navigation so that you can apply an active class to the corresponding anchor tag?

Comment: @AlexDiVito Yes, I am using that function for applying the active class to the tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with the `$routeProvider` service, here's an easy way to accomplish the same task.

JS

```
angular.module('ForeverLeather').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'js/views/home/index.html',
    activetab: 'home'
  })

}]);
```

HTML

```
      <li class="nav-home">
        <a id="home-btn" href="#/home" name="home-btn" ng-class="{active: $route.current.activetab == 'home'}">Home</a>
      </li>
```

using ng-class to determine which tab is active